# how to split the data from sqlite. i need to separate data by each sentence(means split by .)

Tags: android

```
    String subTopicsArray [] = detail.split("\\. ");
    StringBuffer splitTopics = new StringBuffer();

    for(int i=0; i<subTopicsArray.length; i++){     
        String abc=subTopicsArray[i].trim();
        if (abc.length() > 0)
        {
        splitTopics.append(i+1+") "+subTopicsArray[i].trim()+"."+"\n" );
        splitTopics.append("\n");
        }
```

Am using this but am getting two dots for last sentence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use StringTokenizer with deliminator "."

For Example:

```
StringTokenizer st  = new StringTokenizer(detail);
while(st.hasMoreTokens())
{
   st.nextToken();
}
```

Comment: But note that StringTokenizer will not return empty tokens. So if you had "one.two..four" You would get one, then two, then four. Might not be an issue for you though.

Comment: i have an paragraph in database i want split it into a sentence

Comment: my problem in above code ,it was producing two dots in last sentence

Comment: this code is to separate sentence in a paragraph not word because here delieminator is "." (dot) not " "(space).